# How should we tag a medium-ambiguous question?

Tags: discussion, tags

This [hulk](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14261/why-is-the-hulks-skin-green) question spans several mediums: TV, Movie, Comics etc. There's simply not enough room to tag all of these and [avengers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers)[the-incredible-hulk](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-incredible-hulk)[marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics).

How should medium ambiguous questions be tagged? It's been a comic for the longest but the TV and Movie franchise might be more well known.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments, my feeling is that if the question doesn't pertain to a specific medium, no medium tags should be applied.

To me, adding a medium tag indicates that the OP is restricting the scope of the question to that medium (or mediums, if multiple tags are used).

I think this is consistent with how we've been handling other questions, such as [the-walking-dead](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead).

Comment: My issue is that [tag:marvel-comics] is still pseudo-medium specific....

Comment: @Pureferret Then perhaps that tag should be removed as well. I left it because [Marvel Comics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Comics) is the name of the company that holds those ownings, and they, in conjunction with their sister company Marvel Studios, produce adaptations in a variety of media. I'm not sure which, if any, of the other Hulk adaptations were associated with Marvel Comics, so maybe the tag was inappropriate, but I wasn't certain so left it.

Comment: I'd leave it, but I'd be happier with a generic Marvel tag for this sort of situation...